# Requires gitpython module, but not installed or incompatible version: No module named applications.admin.modules.git

Tags: python, python-3.x, web2py, web2py-modules

I'm a beginner denv and I'm using the web2Py framework for web development. And whenever I try to download a template to use, this error appears. I would like to know if anyone who uses this framework has had any problems related to this and the plugins.

I already downloaded and installed the gitpython library

Comment: please add you comment as an edit to the original post. Thank you